# Translation Plugin sending empty content only

Tags: 2013, translation-manager

Until recently we were happily translating content from various publications without issue or concern (SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 // World Server).

We're now seeing that the Tridion Translation Manager appears to be ***removing*** the content from the Translatable fields when it localizes; thus sending empty fields to World Server.

Note that the description below is in an environment with **no** workflow enabled (and  the related event system code **not** enacted) - the initial occurrence lead to a thorough investigate down that path already :(

The schema has the following fields flagged as translatable:

- message
- linkText

The following is the XML of the Component in the EN level (the *source* for the translation)

```
<alert xmlns="uuid:2d8de34f-ed76-4c6c-a622-30bedd5bd7c8">
    <alertTitle xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:740-24958-1024" xlink:title="Alert">Alert</alertTitle>
    <message>I am an alert message - test tr-msa-042</message>
    <linkText>and some linktext too - test tr-msa-042</linkText>
</alert>
```

When the translation is selected, the following is the XML for the localized component at the ES level (the *target* for the translation)

```
<alert xmlns="uuid:2d8de34f-ed76-4c6c-a622-30bedd5bd7c8">
    <alertTitle xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:740-24958-1024" xlink:title="Alert">Alert</alertTitle>
    <message></message>
    <linkText></linkText>
</alert>
```

Note the empty nodes - interestingly, one of these is mandatory and still cleared out!

I've confirmed

- that if I localize the ES level content first the **same results** occur
- the user(s) I've tried running the service as have Impersonation Rights in the snap-in.
- The *Tridion Translation Service* was running as NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService but I've also tried with an admin user with similar rights as MTSUser.

My next path to investigate is permissions in the CM but as these are 'hidden' users I wouldn't expect anything to have changed in the SBX and have been informed there's been no changes in UAT/PRD.

I don't see anything in the logs - perhaps I'm missing a log file to look into?

### UPDATE

In answer to comments form Lars: 
I've also confirmed

- The file sent to WorldServer does not contain the text from the source component - I see the empty nodes, *using the example above* `<ns:message />` & `<ns:linkText />`
- When the item is localized and check out the content remains as expected.
- WorldServer returns items as empty - it also shows a zero word count in the WS GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off...

The specific issue here was a combination of Workflow and having specific schemas enforcing workflow application through bundles.

Answer: 
 - Check if the changes are in workflow - does the service running TM have access to the minor version content (in pre Web8.5 = no)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you with both "Translation Plugin" and "Translation Manager Plugin" mean Tridion Translation Manager (or the short version when it is clear from the context we talk about Tridion: Translation Manager), and not a plugin written for Tridion Translation Manager.

Translation Manager **will not**:

1. Modify the source item that is send for translation.
2. Send the content of the target item for translation (it always send the source).
3. Modify the content of the target item as it is being send for translation.
4. Store content in Tridion bypassing schema validation.

Translation Manager **will**:

1. Check out (and if needed localize) the items in the target publications as they are send for translation.
2. Modify the content of the target items as they are being retrieved.
3. Undo checkout (and potentially unlocalized) items as they are retrieved, or the translation job is cancelled.
4. Save retrieved component through the same calls available to the UI and CoreService when they save - ensuring the same data validation is performed.

The behavior of Translation Manager can be modified by event handlers in Tridion, or by Translation Manager Plugins (in SDL Web 8 you no longer need Translation Manager plugins as Translation Manager will raise events through the same event system as the core SDL Web functions use).

Based on this, I am not convinced the problem is in Translation Manager. You probably want to check the following:

1. Does the file send to WorldServer contain the text from the source component (check this in WorldServer itself). If it does not, something is happening reading the source item, it has nothing to do with the targets.
2. What happens when you localize and check out target items yourself. If you also loose the text in the target items this way, then the problem has nothing to do with Translation Manager.
3. Does WorldServer return items with the translatable text? To check, shut down the Translation Manager windows service and advance a file to the Translated Content Retrieval stage in the WorldServer workflow. Then check the file in the WorldServer file system.

Comment: Thanks Lars - I've done the additional checks you recommend and have added the 'update' above.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that the items without the mandatory fields are stored in Tridion? They are not just what you see in WorldServer? If this is the case first check you have no event handlers that could cause this, then contact support. There is no need to check permissions, as Tridion does not have any permission that should allow storing content not matching the Schema.

Comment: I'll contact support - Having removed all extensions / event handlers etc. I am now seeing the issue reported here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/under-what-condition-would-translation-manager-undo-the-checkout-a-component