# Under what condition would Translation Manager unlocalize a translated component

Tags: 2013, translation-manager

SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1, Translation Manager + World Server.

We've been having an issue with Translation Manager documented [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14474/translation-plugin-sending-empty-content-only) - in seeking to find the root cause we've removed all event system handlers (in fact, we've removed all extensions too).

I'm now seeing the that

- the translation layer component is localized
- the content for the translation layer component in World Server is the correct content
- World Server translates the content
- The localized component is **unlocalized** (see logs below)

There are **no** errors reported in the logs.

Under what conditions would Translation Manager perform and **unlocalize** - especially on the return of content from World Server?

Log Snippet:

Short Version:

> 2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation 
>   **Undoing checkout for item**
>   "it.accountActivity.transactions.description" (tcm:719-30076).
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   **CoreServiceProxy.UndoCheckoutItem** tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.UndoCheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation 
>   **Unlocalizing item** "it.accountActivity.transactions.description"
>   (tcm:719-30076)
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.UnLocalizeItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:52   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.**UnLocalizeItem** tcmUri=tcm:719-30076

More info:

> 2016-04-21T23:18:45   w3wp    36  TcmClient proxy created for user
>   "CORP\a683643". 2016-04-21T23:18:45   w3wp    36  Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser 2016-04-21T23:18:45    w3wp    36  Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetLoggedUser 2016-04-21T23:18:46    w3wp    36  Disposing
>   service client
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Retreiving
>   translation management system item with id "cmpx0" for language
>   "1047".
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   WorldServerTranslationSystemItem.RetrieveItem.download
>   targetPath=/Clients/Account
>   Center/Projects/2504_itaccountActivitytransactionsdescription/Target-Spanish
>   (United States)/grouped item properties.cmpx
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   WorldServerTranslationSystemItem.RetrieveItem.download
>   targetPath=/Clients/Account
>   Center/Projects/2504_itaccountActivitytransactionsdescription/Target-Spanish
>   (United States)/grouped item properties.cmpx
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:10-30076-v14
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:10-30076-v14
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:10-29164-8
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItemDataWithCache tcmUri=tcm:10-29164-8
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:10-29164-8
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList
>   tcmUri=tcm:10-29164-8
>   2016-04-21T23:18:48   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain.GetSystemWideList
>   tcmUri=tcm:10-29164-8
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetBluePrintChain tcmUri=tcm:10-29164-8
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-29164-8
>   key=tm:TranslationSchema
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:4-29164-8
>   key=tm:TranslationSchema
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetPathToRootOrgItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Storing
>   retrieved translation in the item with id "tcm:719-30076".
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.CheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.CheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:49   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.UpdateXml tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.UpdateXml tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.CheckinItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076-v0
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.CheckinItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076-v0
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:719-30076-v0
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.IsExistingObject tcmUri=tcm:719-30076-v0
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076-v0
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:50   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.SetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076-v0
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Completing
>   the translation management system job "2504" belonging to the
>   Translation Job "it.accountActivity.transactions.description".
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=null key=tm:cache
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetAppData tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   key=tm:TranslationInfo
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.GetItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation 
>   Undoing checkout for item
>   "it.accountActivity.transactions.description" (tcm:719-30076).
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.UndoCheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.UndoCheckoutItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation 
>   Unlocalizing item "it.accountActivity.transactions.description"
>   (tcm:719-30076)
>   2016-04-21T23:18:51   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Entry
>   CoreServiceProxy.UnLocalizeItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076
>   2016-04-21T23:18:52   Tridion.TranslationManager.Service  RetrieveFromTranslation Exit
>   CoreServiceProxy.UnLocalizeItem tcmUri=tcm:719-30076

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, many use cases and tweaking later I can see the specific scenario that will reproduce this. I've documented it here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/translation-manager-would-it-ever-unlocalize-something-in-my-translation-publication

**Essentially**

1. The Component is based on a Schema that has the option below checked:

> Any changes made to a Component based on this Schema require approval
>   by a Bundle Workflow Process.

2. The Component is not in an **active** workflow bundle

Answer (score 3):

Please install this hotfix:

TT88491: Translation Manager revert retrieved translation for target item in "Reserved state"

or a newer hotfix (as newer hotfixes will include this fix).

Comment: Lars - given the specific scenario is this hotfix still relevant to this scenario? It looks like it offers a few improvements for things we've just suffered to date so we're reviewing it all the same but I want to confirm if the expectation is that this will clear it off to inform the testers. Thanks again.

Comment: Your case is the exact case the hotfix is covering.

Comment: Yeah, when a component _must_ go into workflow, but is not, it is in what we call "Reserved State".

Comment: Thanks for that (both) - hotfix implementation is requested - will mark as the answer once confirmed :)